# Fn keys for Brightness not working on Toshiba Satellite L755

Tags: 12.04, brightness, toshiba-satellite

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I love it! The only problem is the keys for my brightness, <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd>, does not work when I am on battery power or AC power. It randomly works after I am idle for a while and log back in. The other weird thing is to see my battery indicator, I need to toggle my touch pad button that is right above the actual pad on and off for it to show up, and then back on so I can use my touch pad, obviously. The only other <kbd>Fn</kbd> buttons that work on my laptop is the button to mute <kbd>F1</kbd> Touch pad on and off <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> for my volume.

The only <kbd>Fn</kbd> buttons that I care if they work again are my brightness, which again, are <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/935778

This is a known bug for Toshiba Laptops. It states that booting normally, the brightness keys work, and then after suspending, it does not. Only after a normal boot does it work again.

My problem is the exact opposite: normal boot, brightness keys do not work; after suspending, they do work.

Comment: Not to be impatient, but is my issue too specific? Is there a certain thread I should have gone with my question?