# Function keys are not working on Toshiba Satellite L510 so brightness control is not possible

Tags: function-keys

I am using Toshiba L510 AND Ubuntu 12.04.  I Cannot control brightness of my system using function keys.  What could be the cause?

Comment: Does changing brightness any other way works? For, example, from the Power Management? Can you add the output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/` to the question.

Comment: Looks like similar to [this problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130819/toshiba-l745-brightness-problem-fn-keys-doesnt-works?rq=1) -- on the other hand, I found a related package in the repositories, `toshset` maybe it's worth checking out. [redshift](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9248/is-there-a-software-utility-to-adjust-screen-gamma-brightness-contrast) was also recommended

Comment: These function keys normally talk directly to BIOS, and are not visible to OS (Windows or Ubuntu).  What key-combinations are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148365/fn-keys-for-brightness-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-l755

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal using `Ctrl+Alt+t` and type `sudo apt-get install xbacklight`. That will install [xbacklight](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xbacklight) [image: Install xbacklight] if it isn't already there (I can't remember whether it's a default package!).

Then type `xbacklight -set x` **replacing the x with a number between 1 and  99** to set the percentage brightness for your screen backlight. You can actually set to 0 (and I do because I hate bright screens) but I understand that can cause problems on some displays so I don't recommend trying it.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add, you can then set a keyboard shortcut to something like `xbacklight -inc 10` to increase the brightness by 10%.

Unfortunately, you can't use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Another Key</kbd> since like he said, <kbd>Fn</kbd> is reserved for the BIOS. It's weird because my <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> works in turning off/on the screen, and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> works in turning off (but not on) my wifi, but <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> do not adjust brightness... Hope someone can find a real fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` as a boot option. To do that, open a terminal window, and run

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
Locate this line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="".
```

Edit it to look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Save the file, then, in a terminal, run `sudo update-grub`.

Reboot, and check if the brightness keys work.

That worked for me!

<sup>Related link : [Brightness function keys not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266046/brightness-function-keys-not-working/266056#266056)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Toshiba

I installed `fnfxd` package search *synaptics Package Manger* for it or

```
sudo apt-get install fnfxd
```

It solved my problem

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: I have a Satellite L55-b5338 running Zorin. This worked for my volume control and brightness, but not my wifi toggle or my touchpad enable/disable. I'll see if I can find commands to bind for those.

Answer (score 0):

This has fixed it both on a Toshiba L510 and a P850.

1) Edit /etc/default/grub and change this variable:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=legacy"
```

2) Edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add this line at the end of the file:

```
blacklist toshiba_acpi
```

3) Update the grub config file:

```
sudo update-grub
```

4.) Reboot.