# Brightness function keys not working

Tags: 12.10, laptop, brightness, function-keys

I have an  ASUS X55A-SPD0204O laptop. The rest of the FN+Fx (where x = number) like sound + - mute, screen turn off, wireless etc. work perfectly.

The problem is with the 2 brightness keys. They just won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please add the output of `ls /sys/class/backlight` and of `cat /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` to the question.

Comment: I'd also be interested in seeing the output of `lspci | grep -i vga`, as we might be dealing with hybrid graphics.

Comment: Why is this question closed as "has been asked before" with a reference to a question asked *after* this one? Not to mention that the referenced question in turn actually references this question.

Answer (score 13):

Try adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` as a boot option. To do that, open a terminal window, and run

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Locate this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`.

Edit it to look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Save the file, then, in a terminal, run `sudo update-grub`.

Reboot, and check if the brightness keys work.

Comment: Worked perfectly for my Asus UL50VT. Been trying to fix this problem for several years now. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work

Comment: nope, doesn't work for me too. The indicator doesn't even pops up when i press those keys.

Comment: @Dialogos, try `acpi_osi=Linux` or `acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=vendor`; I hope one of these will help.

Comment: Neither `acpi_backlight=vendor` nor `acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=vendor` worked for me. The working one for me was `acpi_osi=Linux` as @AliNa commented. *Debian Wheezy on Asus UX50V Laptop*

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 14.04, HP Pavilion G6. Thanks!

Comment: `acpi_osi_Linux` did it for me, too, thanks @Stichoza

Comment: First suggestion solved it for me on Ubuntu 14.04 running on a Lenovo ThinkPad

Comment: `acpi_osi=Linux` worked for me on 16.10, but there is no OSD when changing the brightness with the keys. Is that to be expected or can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to control it from command line and give mesage back if this works in general:

You will need `xrandr`

`xrandr --current --verbose` - this will display your current display mode / modes

important is name of your output (clould be `LVDS1` or `LVDS-0`)

`xrandr --output <outputname> --brightness 0.5` - this should control your brightnes, you can try different values. Do not use zero (0) what means lamp is switched off and you will see Big nothing.
be careful, some types of devices have completely different set of values (as 0-255, etc. Unfortunatelly I do not have your ASUS to test it)

This will work probably independently of the brightness settings reachable normally via keys. If this works, I recommend to watch for key bindings. Advantage is, you can control brightness of external VGA output as well.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the grub and try you may be able to get the brightness working properly. You may follow this [**link**](http://www.refreshit.info/2012/08/solved-brightness-increase-and-decrease.html) and to upgrade and fix the brightness problem for your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to change the brightness in system settings (Power manager)? 
If yes, then maybe just keys are not binded.

You could install xbacklight and bind your special keys to appropriate commands.

Comment: yes i can change it manually.

Answer (score 0):

try that .. i had your same problem and it work with me

Open a terminal window and type the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

This will open your X server configuration (after prompting for your password). You should see a section titled "Device" that looks as follows:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection
```

Append a line so it appears like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
        Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

You will need to restart your graphical server (or reboot) for this change to take effect.

PS: I tried all suggested solutions here and nothing worked with me!

Comment: there's no such file.

Comment: @Dialogos http://askubuntu.com/questions/217758/how-to-make-an-xorg-conf-file

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there are 2 solutions for this problem, but sometimes none of these work. I tried changing the boot options (editing-updating grub and stuff) and that didn't work. As I have seen in many forums (and in my case too), the change in the xorg.conf file won't work because there is no such file... so?

After searching a couple hours, I found something interesting:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo reboot
```

those lines supposedly get the driver working as it should, but the original problem remains. The important thing is that those lines CREATE the *xorg.conf*  file, so now it is possible to apply the second solution (adding the `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` line to the file).

Hope this helps someone, I used this on a Samsung R580, with a Nvidia GeForce310m and worked just fine.

By the way, I used `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` instead of the `nano` command, it's just a matter of tastes I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Try this app .. for problem in brightness controlling. Use the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [ubuntu.com](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/thumbnail/225x170/appmedia/2014/01/brightness-controller_mac2_1.png))</sub>

I was also searching stuff related to driver , but at last I found this app .
I am having ubuntu - 12.04 on Sony - vaio, working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

just install power-manager relative to your xwindow system (eg. I use xfce4-power-manager). That solves the screen brightness adjusting from fn keys without messing around with grub.