# How to link brightness button to correct brightness script

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, laptop, brightness

I recently upgrade my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04. My laptop has always had incomtibility issues between the brightness button and the actual brightness set up. In 12.04 I had fixed the problem by doing the following (**but this does not work anymore**):

1. Adding to `/etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-up`

   ```
   event=video DD02 00000086 00000000
   action=/etc/acpi/brightup.sh
   ```
2. And to `/etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-down`

   ```
   event=video DD02 00000087 00000000
   action=/etc/acpi/brightdown.sh
   ```

That way I link my brightness buttons to the following scripts that set the actual screen brightness.

1. Brightness up `/etc/acpi/brightup.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   curr=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness`
   if [ $curr -lt 4677 ]; then
      curr=$((curr+200));
      echo $curr  > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness;
   fi
   ```
2. Brightness down `/etc/acpi/brightdown.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   curr=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness`
   if [ $curr -gt 200 ]; then
      curr=$((curr-200));
      echo $curr  > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness;
   fi
   ```

After making them executables and restarting acpid my brightness buttons were working all right.

**However that does not fix the problem anymore**, but if I manually set an X value in the file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` I can see a decrease or increase in the screen brightness. Why is it that the link between the button and the scripts no longer works in Ubuntu 14.04?

It may be worth to mention that my shorrcuts for brightness do work, because when I press either `Fn` + `F5` or `Fn` + `F6` I see the brighness bar going up or down.

Comment: What about the fn keys? Try using the steps outline in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop#answer-603980) and report back.

Comment: This does not work for me. It may be worth to mention that my shorrcuts for brightness do work, because when I press either `Fn` + `F5` or `Fn` + `F6` I see the brighness bar going up or down.