# Asus UX303LA fn brightness keys not working

Tags: function-keys

I've searched everywhere for a solution.

I've tried this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi="
```

each variable on it's own and different combinations. Also `acpi_osi=Linux`

In all of them fn+f5 and fn+f6 (for brighness) fn+f2 (for airplane mode) doesn't work. They don't even register in `acpi_listen` or `xev`.

Comment: I dont think all the acpi packages are installed by default anymore; have you installed all the relevant acpi dependencies?

Comment: @mchid I installed them, didn't help!

Comment: also, I believe you are supposed to have acpi_backlight=vendor or acpi_osi= as others have reported acpi_osi= not working with acpi_backlight=vendor present http://askubuntu.com/a/603980/167115

Comment: [I fixed this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cant-change-brightness-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/862156#862156) on other model of UX303, on UX303UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those keys don't have acpi functionality, you can set the function manually through ccsm using xbacklight commands.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager xbacklight
```

- Now, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type ccsm, and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
- Next, enable the **commands** plugin and then click on the **commands** plugin.
- Enter the command **command line 0**.
- Click on the **key bindings** tab and click **disabled** on the **command line 0** row.
- Check the **enabled** box, click **grab key combination** and then press the key combo you would like to use to increase the brightness (<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> for example). Click okay.
- Finally, do the same for "command line 1" to set the brightness decrease except use the command `xbacklight -dec 10` and use a different key combo (of course).

Thanks to [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/471948/167115) provided by @TejasGhalsasi

---

You can set similar keyboard combos for other functions. The command to turn off wifi is:

```
nmcli r wifi off
```

and the command to turn wifi back on is:

```
nmcli r wifi on
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I can't upvote you but this really helped me. Thanks again for putting the time to write all this.

Comment: @Atrotors also, I think airplane mode is actually `nmcli r all off` not sure if that covers Bluetooth

Comment: My combo grab is weird. It wont pick up, fn + (F1, F6, F8, F9) (wifi, mouse screen dim, screen bright) but will pick up fn + (F2, F3, F4, F5, F7) blank, mute, vol down, vol up, blank. wifi and screen dont work at all, mouse and volume do. This is very very strange to say the least. i cant see why some work and some dont, its not duff buttons because the keys all work without fn pressed

Comment: @Chris It depends on the model. Some models, like toshiba, apple, and thinkpads have packages that are available through apt-get that enable the fn keys. Use apt-cache search to search for these. Also, enabling acpi sometimes helps.