# Custom Function Keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness

The brightness keys don't work on the UX305 so I managed to bind Ctrl+F5/6 to execute

> xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightness{Up/Down}

While this works fine and even shows the visual notification but the whole thing feels a little hacky. Is there a way to bind the shortcut to the actual Fn keys? Xev doesn't do anything when you press Fn+F5/6 so thats that....

Comment: mchid: No unfortunately Fn+F5 doesn't do anything at all. Even xev doesn't report anything when you press that combo.

Comment: so you tried to set this using ccsm? because the other user had the same response from xev but it worked for them using the grab key combo method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asus UX303LA fn brightness keys not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/656258/asus-ux303la-fn-brightness-keys-not-working)

Comment: [I fixed this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cant-change-brightness-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/862156#862156) on other model of UX303, on UX303UB. I now have your problem trying to use Fn+F7 to turn off screen with `xset dpms force standby`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm myself a KDE user, so I won't tell you exactly how to change the global shortcuts in Ubuntu, but I think this is what you are actually trying to do. The global shortcut for brightness change is assigned to XF86MonBrightnessUp/Down and you should be able to change it to whatever else you want, e.g. Ctrl+F5/6.

This guide seems to be describing how to do this in Ubuntu:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html