# Cannot change brightness (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Unity)

Tags: screen, brightness, 16.04

I'm new to Linux systems in general (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and I'm having difficulty in changing the brightness of my notebook.

When I use the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> the brightness bar shows up but there is no change in the actual brightness of the screen.

I tried every method described in this post ([How to adjust screen brightness in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540911/how-to-adjust-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu-14-04)) to no success.
Installing and using the xbacklight has no effect, same for editing the brightness file in the "intel_backlight" file.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: I had the same problem using Toshiba C660 satelite a few years back. It wouldn't work, until I used the nvidia driver from the "additional drivers" tab, couldn't get it to fix, using the open-source driver. Does it happen to you, which driver are you using?

Comment: I think you should add at least the model name

Comment: The graphics card is an Intel® HD Graphics 3000.  I'm still not very familiar with the way linux handles the computer drivers and all, so I'm not sure what do you mean about "additional drivers tab".

Comment: I found a strange workaround on my laptop (compaq cq70). Instead of pressing Fn+f7 to dim and Fn+f8 to brighten, I am able to use Ctrl+f10 to dim and press Ctrl+f11 to brighten.

Comment: This is still not working even in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This method does not work when nightlight/redshift is enabled, and also does not work with Wayland.

---

This does not make your brightness function keys work, but is a workaround.

Install [Brightness Controller](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness) with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
```

For Version 2 with Multi Monitor Support and Color Temperature support:

```
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

[image]

For Version 1 with up to 4 Monitor Support:

```
sudo apt install brightness-controller-simple
```

[image: Brightness Controller Version 1]
(Note: Version 1 is not anymore updated)

**Note:** This does not decrease the intensity of backlight, so won't save your batteries. But you can use this as a last resort to save your eyes. This also works in desktops, where there is no option to control brightness.

Comment: This not a brigthness controller.  This just play with colors of system

Comment: @HarshitChaudhary you  are right..this is a bug with this version.Thanks!

Comment: Refer this link  for more details  https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/1270579

Comment: Finally I can set the brightness. For some reason I only have primary brightness, secondary isn't working. And clearly it is secondary brightness that is used by settings menu and xbacklight. All the various grub solutions didn't work for me (I tried many of them). [I am on an ASUS A555U, ubuntu 16.04 - to spare anyone else the effort]

Comment: @JasoonS You don't have access to secondary brightness as your computer is connected to only one monitor.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks, that makes sense. Well bottom line, this worked, so (y)

Comment: @HarshitChaudhary Currently it seems to control the brightness well, as it claims. Not the colors.

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all. The brightness controller window says "Primary Not Found" and that's that. No controls, nothing. I don't get how this is such a big issue. Ubuntu should be able to handle this out of the box. :(

Comment: Hello - dialog box comes up, but no effect: 14.04 on MSI laptop with hybrid Intel graphics on the motherboard and NVIDIA (boo) as the standalone.  Running `brightness-controller` on the command line I get `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default` on the first line, then `xrandr: Gamma size is 0.` each time I adjust the slider.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04 + Asus ROG. 
1) Set acpi_backlight = native in grub (If you're looking at this page, you probably tried the grub already)

2) I needed to quit flux / redshift for this application to take effect. Screen brightness is controllable now PLUS the added benefit of the "flux effect". Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: This does not work together with Ubutu 18.04 Nightlight. Nightlight is disabled when I change any slider in the brightness controller.

Answer (score 37):

## Hardware brightness buttons

### Since Ubuntu LTS 18.04

Here is every step required for `xbacklight` control:

1. `$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and [replace the corresponding line with](https://askubuntu.com/a/426266/164341) `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
2. `$ sudo update-grub`
3. No joking, make sure that the [appropriate drivers are actually installed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851810#25): `$ sudo apt install xbacklight xorg xserver-xorg-video-intel`
4. Issuing `$ find /sys -type f -name brightness` should yield something like `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness`
5. `$ cd /sys/class` This directory should contain a soft link called `brightness` to the brightness device discovered in the previous step. Should it be missing, create it: `$ sudo ln -s /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness /sys/class/brightness`
6. `$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf` should read:

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier      "Device0"
       Driver          "intel"
       Option          "Backlight"      "intel_backlight"
   EndSection

   Section "Monitor"
       Identifier      "Monitor0"
   EndSection

   Section "Screen"
       Identifier      "Screen0"
       Monitor         "Monitor0"
       Device          "Device0"
   EndSection
   ```

   If it doesn't, edit it with `$ sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
7. The assignment of the physical `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` keys is [explained here for Xubuntu LTS or XFCE users](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080149/164341).
8. Finally, **reboot** for these changes to take effect.

### Finer-grained brightness control (all Ubuntu versions)

If brightness control happens to be too coarse, then make this [additional adjustment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080149/164341).

### Ubuntu LTS 16.04

To find out if you have integrated Intel video graphics, enter the following command:

```
$ ls /sys/class/backlight/
    intel_backlight  panasonic
```

At least `intel_backlight` should be mentioned, most probably in addition to an OEM name like for example `panasonic`, `dell_backlight`, etc.

If this is the case, proceed with creating the following file

```
$ sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

containing the following lines:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Reboot, and enjoy your backlight buttons! [[Source]](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)

### Before Ubuntu LTS 16.04

Under (X)Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, brightness control on my [Panasonic Toughbook CF-52](https://www.cnet.com/products/panasonic-toughbook-cf-52/specs/) used to work fine by adding
`acpi_osi=Linux` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

and issuing

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

after editing and before rebooting.

Comment: I tried this fix on my laptop which has an integrated Intel gfx card (with a backlight as revealed by the ls command as suggested), and with 2nd Nvidia 960M as well. On reboot I get a purple screen,  but nothing else being displayed - I can change the background brightness, but I can't log in, as I can't see anything on the screen except a full screen purple wash.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 You have what is called a [hybrid graphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) environment, which is a bit problematic. Personally, I have no experience with that. However, following above link will provide you with some answers.

Comment: Solved my issue with Lenovo W520 @ Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You can also read/write to the device file (as root), eg in my case: "echo 45 > /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness" .  Appears to be a range of 0-255.

Comment: This answers even works for me!!!. I am Linux mit xfce user.thanks alot Gin Gordon

Comment: Fixed issue  on 17.04 Ubuntu as well, fn keys now work again to control brightness.

Comment: The post-16.04 version also works on Debian Stretch

Comment: work on ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo W520

Comment: works for a Dell Inspiron 7370  on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @SergeStroobandt  sudo ln -s /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness /sys/class/brightness
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sys/class/brightness': Operation not permitted
What should i do?

Comment: @Pranav did you solve the `ln` issue?

Comment: Does Unity still use the X11 config??

Answer (score 6):

Another option is the application [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/), which in addition to adjusting brightness can also adjust the color temperature to reduce the blue light at night.

Example usage: `redshift -b 0.8` will set the brightness to 0.8 on a scale of 0 to 1

Comment: When using redshift, I get the problem of multiple commands being stacked, causing the screen to flicker. If i close my terminal, redshift stops working

Comment: From Redshift docs: *Redshift has a brightness adjustment setting, but it does not work the way most people might expect. In fact it is a fake brightness adjustment obtained by manipulating the gamma ramps, which means that it does **not** reduce the backlight of the screen.*

Answer (score 5):

I use Lenovo Z570 and adding `acpi_backlight=none` to `/etc/default/grub` and updating grub worked nicely with <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

Comment: This one worked for me (Sony Vaio VPCEG30EL)

Answer (score 2):

In XFCE, you must enable "Handle display brightness keys" on XFCE Power Manager, under the  General tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 16.04 there is a package in the repos called "backlight-indicator" which will use your camera to set backlight (or not) and differentially set it for AC and/or battery usage.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package backlight-indicator`                                            `No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial`

Comment: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/atareao_atareao/xenial/main/base/backlight-indicator

Comment: you should add this @Enigma ppa:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao `

Answer (score 1):

For AMD Radeon Graphics Card on Ubuntu 22.04 (this closely follows [Serge's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/859480/824343):

- Install pre-requisite packages:

  ```
  sudo apt install xbacklight
  sudo apt install xorg
  ```
- Find brightness config file

  ```
  sudo find /sys -type f -name brightness
  ```
- You may see multiple options, but the one indicating the graphics driver will be needed. In my case, its:

  ```
  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.0/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/brightness
  ```
- Create / edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` so that it looks like:

  ```
  Section "Device"
      Identifier      "Device0"
      Driver          "amd"
      Option          "Backlight"      "amdgpu_bl1"
  EndSection

  Section "Monitor"
      Identifier      "Monitor0"
  EndSection

  Section "Screen"
      Identifier      "Screen0"
      Monitor         "Monitor0"
      Device          "Device0"
  EndSection
  ```
- Edit parameter `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the GRUB file `/etc/default/grub` to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
  ```
- Update the GRUB file

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my Asus UX303UB with a little difference:

- set to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="` (acpi_osi= did it for me, other options didn't work, got this from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04)). Of course after this run `update-grub`. This make function keys respond showing the Ubuntu notification, but doesn't really change brightness. One more thing taken from other answers:
- `sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

with contents:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Now the only problem is to associate Fn+F7 to `xset dpms force standby` to turn off the screen.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got black screen after login.

Comment: This command spoiled my system. Got stuck during booting. Don't try this.

Comment: @sv_jan5 @JordanSilva  Strange, do you have 16.04.02? Exactly [Asus UX303UB](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX303UB/)? Check with `lsb_release -a` and `sudo dmidecode -t baseboard`.

Comment: `lsb_release -a` gave:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was because of some issue with my graphics drivers. Changing them to a stable version solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a **Panasonic CF-LX3**, and it reports as having 2 brightness controls:

```
/sys/class/backlight/:
intel_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight
panasonic -> ../../devices/virtual/backlight/panasonic
```

But actually on this machine the *first* one works and the vendor one doesn't.

So adding **`acpi_brightness=video`** to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/defaults/grub` helped.

(don't forget to `update-grub`)

Answer (score 0):

After following the accepted answers, it still did not work in Ubuntu 18.04. Then, I changed `/etc/default/grub` to contain the line:

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=none"
```

Instead of:

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

And run:

```bash
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Nothing works..