# Changing brightness settings has no effect on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: laptop, screen, brightness, 20.10, backlight

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Ubuntu 20.04 brightness adjust not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working), [Cannot change brightness (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and onward)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cannot-change-brightness-ubuntu-16-04-lts-and-onward) or [Unable to change brightness in settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871298/unable-to-change-brightness-in-settings/871579#871579) because the answers do not fix the problem.

On Dell Inspiron 11, Ubuntu 20.10, I enabled the brightness laptop keys and Settings Power panel brightness slider by adding `acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux` to `/etc/default/grub` based on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162667/656585).

Following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/859480/656585), I installed `xbacklight` and `$ find /sys -type f -name brightness` returned:

```
/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/leds/phy0-led/brightness
```

But I was unable to add a softlink:

```
$ sudo ln -s /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness /sys/class/brightness
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sys/class/brightness': Operation not permitted
```

I created `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with these contents:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "dell_backlight"
EndSection
```

And rebooted, but the brightness does not change when I adjust the slider or use the brightness keys.

What else can I try here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 brightness adjust not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working)

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Please see the note and link at the top of the post.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the "question" in that post is extremely vague and none of the proposed solutions in that post are marked as answering the "question."