# How to change brighness on Lubuntu desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, lxde

I'd like to reduce the screen brightness on my Lubuntu desktop (Ubuntu 16.04).

I googled but could not find any soluton that works. (like using `xbacklight -set 45` command.

Appreciate a simple working solution.

Comment: I believe you can change it in the power settings but I don't have my laptop handy and by the time I grab it someone will probably answer this already .. check your "start .. Settings... power manager" settings

Comment: Well in System>Preferences>Xfce Powermanger I see no slider/option to change brightness.

Comment: I found a slider on the batter icon in the tray but that one doesn't seem to do anything on mine ... I see someone posted an answer below so maybe that will be more sufficient :D

Comment: ok I was not able to use anything on ubuntu but .. on my laptop `fn + F5` lowers my brightness and `fn + F6` raises it but on the screen .. it doesn't seem to lower the brightness in the "on screen display" .. the screen seems the same brightness until the OSD goes to 0 and if I keep hitting it .. it starts to dim after the meter drops to 0 on the display .. if that makes sense :)

Comment: I found the fix [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cant-change-brightness-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) in the answer that starts with `Pre Ubuntu LTS 16.04` I used what it said in `Since Ubuntu LTS 16.04` the `ls` command showed `intel_backlight` so I added the stuff he said in nano and rebooted .. now my `fn` buttons work correctly and the battery icon when I click on it and use the Display brightness .. that works too

Answer (score 0):

execute any of these inside root terminal

`echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
 sudo echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

if `/sys/class/backlight/` folder is empty

`nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
 add this to kernel line

`acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor`

or

`nano /etc/default/grub`

see a line like **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT**
and add

`acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor`

save and run

`update-grub`

to save changes to grub

`reboot`

......

Comment: need one more edit .. the `nano /etc/derfauls/grub` to `nano /etc/default/grub`

Comment: I see `# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE` on grub.cfg. I'm not going to mess with kernel to set the brightness. There should be a better way.

Comment: changed as@John Orion; @Babr the `grub.cfg` is a temporary solution.. its overridden every time by kernel updates; the permanent solution is `/etc/defalts/grub`; anw you need mods to grub only if `/sys/class/backlight` folder is empty

Comment: you can add it in `sudo /etc/default/grub` and then run `sudo update-grub` I would not do it in the grub.cfg file

Comment: but after adding it to my grub file .. I still see on my battery icon a place to change display brightness but .. it still doesn't work properly :(

Comment: did you tested the CLI terminal lines? do they work? is/was your backlight folder empty?

Comment: no .. they both gave errors .. not found.. but im having issues with the linux install ... and its using old kernel still .. cant get it to upgrade yet ... working on that before I can try those things again.. lol at the moment im installing about 150 updates

Comment: can you post result of `cat /proc/cmdline`?

Comment: like I say .. at this time im not able to do much .. im still on 4.4.0-21 so im very far behind .. getting current before I try those things again .. as for the command you listed it shows the lines added.. I don't have this open on the laptop so I cant copy and paste and as I say at the moment im upgrading to get to current first

Answer (score 0):

I use Lubuntu with an Nvidia graphics card.  The brightness setting is in the "NVIDIA X Server Settings" app.  It's kind of buried though - you have to select the "HDMI-0" from the menu on the left, and then click the "color correction" tab.

You don't mention your graphics hardware, but if you don't use Nvidida, perhaps the setting is related to your graphics card as well.