# xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Tags: 18.04, brightness, xrandr, amd-ryzen, msi

### Problem:

I can't adjust my brightness in ubuntu 18. The keyboard buttons, the slider, the terminal commands, none of them are working.

#### What I've tried:

- installing an [application](https://askubuntu.com/a/763010/1185553), but it had no effect.
- using xrandr commands like --brightness
- editing grub file, like `acpi=off`, `vendor`, `video`, etc.
- but, none of them worked out (;-;)

Can anyone help me out with this issue, thanks in advance.

#### Sample outputs:

```
~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00* 
~$ xrandr --output default --brightness 0.4
xrandr: Gamma size is 0.
```

#### Background:

I'm using MSI modern 14, ryzen 4500u variant, with AMD radeon graphics. I have no experience with ubuntu before, and I'm totally new to this OS.

---

The application suggested by @andrew.46 gives no error, but it doesn't change the brightness, the following is the output:

```
~$ sudo brightnessctl s 50%
Updated device 'input4::capslock':
Device 'input4::capslock' of class 'leds':
    Current brightness: 1 (100%)
    Max brightness: 1
```

Comment: @andrew.46 - I already have this (brightness-controller app) and redshift, it's GUI sliders have no effect on brightness. And the redshift too gave the same disappointment.

Comment: Yes I eventually saw that and deleted my comment too slowly :). Have you experimented with `xbacklight`? I am not sure that this will work with your hardware though, specifically the AMD Radeon graphics...

Comment: If this is a no go I believe there is another application `brightnessctl` that might be worth looking at: https://www.mankier.com/1/brightnessctl

Comment: Ubuntu has both releases that use *yy* format (*snap* only, longer supported lives with everything running containerized) and the stadnard *yy.mm* releases that use *deb* packages... You use both in your question (they refer to different products) so please clarify.  Also I did testing on brightness/backlight/etc over ~20 devices and they differ from the same commands, depending on graphics cards in use (plus internal/external displays..), but I'd suggest redshift & manual edit of .conf file

Comment: @andrew.46 - I used `brightnessctl` and it works without errors, but it didn't had any effect, sadly. It changed current brightness, but not max brightness. Hence, the brightness is still constant :\