# 21.10 : Brightness stopped working (yes one more topic about that... :/ )

Tags: drivers, brightness, xrandr, amd-ryzen

I saw many threads about this but sadly none helped.... so here comes back the brightness problem on Ubuntu 21.10.

## Problem

On Ubuntu 21.10 brightness control stopped working, brightness is now always at 100%.

It used to work (and pissed me off because brightness fell down everytime I plugged in AC adaptor), and it's broken for some days/weeks maximum. It could be since upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10 from 21.04, or after a classic package upgrade... I sadly haven't noticed the exact day.

## What I tried

1. Using the brightness slider : no effect
2. Using the keyboard : no effect (I see a hover window with a slider moving, but no change on brightness)
3. Switching on/off the night mode : no effect (it 6 a.m. here and my eyes a crying because of the strong white light)
4. Changing default grub options to add `acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux` : this made the problem worse as the previously not working brightness slider completely disappeared. I switched back to default.
5. Installed `brightnessctl` : command execution is OK and displays different % of brightness, but screen actually remains at full brightness
6. Installed `xbacklight` : same as 2.
7. Installed `ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller` : nothing changes but I see errors in the terminal : `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

When executing this command manually I see the same output :

```
$ xrandr 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

## My configuration

Huawei Matebook 14, AMD Ryzen 5

```
$ lspci|grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2)
```

## Other threads found, but not helping

- [On Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cannot-change-brightness-ubuntu-16-04-lts-unity/763010#763010)
- [On Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts)
- [On Ubuntu 18.XX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319944/xrandr-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default)
- [On Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working)

## My guesses

I suspect some display driver problem, as I also noticed some display artefacts lately. When scrolling a web page some parts are scrolling faster than the others, and after 1-2 seconds the display corrects everything.

It's better with an image (I used gimp to simulate what I see) :

[image]

**Edit :** My laptop screen also stays black after closing/reopening the lid, instead of coming back to life... I have to force shut down / restart.

I am not using any additionnal grapics driver.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks to [another website](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1128811) linking to [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252416/ubuntu-20-04-intel-hd-615-no-brightness-control-or-no-boot-stuck-on-boot-scre). When I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 I had to add `nomodeset` to grub parameters, otherwise Ubuntu kept getting stuck at boot.

Removing this parameter now has fixed the brightness, and boot is still OK. I guess some bug has been fixed since my upgrade :)