# Fn+F5/6 Brightness shortcut not working - Asus laptop - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, brightness, asus, function-keys

The brightness function keys on my Asus laptop don't work on Ubuntu. The function key combinations for sound volume (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>/<kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F10</kbd>) and turning the screen on and off (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>), but not those that should adjust the brightness (<kbd>Fn+F6/F5</kbd>)...

After some, I tried [this itsfoss.com article](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310), but it still doesn't work.

I tried [Brightness fn key shortcut doesn't work on ASUS laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop) but again no success.

What else can I try?

Comment: Actually, you should post the solution in the answer section.  You're not prohibited from that

Comment: Even though that question is mentioned here as not having worked, the OP's own solution is very similar to the solution [given in that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/841903/22949). The question itself seems to be the same and the OP's problem is solved here; the answers are slightly different, and we could perhaps merge after closing.

Answer (score 2):

OP's answer removed from the question and edited slightly:

> I found the solution [on this webpage (in
>   French)](http://univers.binaires.free.fr/art.php?p=25).
>
> It tells us to
>
> ```
> sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> then find this line
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> ```
>
> and add a parameters `acpi_osi=` and `acpi_backlight=intel`, so the
>   edited line reads:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=intel"
> ```
>
> save the file, and then to make changes effective, run
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> finally you turn off / restart your monster and it should work!!*
>
> I should mention that I still have the
>   `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file as described in the
>   [first article](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) I
>   linked to in my question.**

* **CW post author's note**: You may want to try the boot parameters individually first, rather than together. `acpi_backlight=intel` should be tried alone first as it has less wide-ranging effects. Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after each change made to `/etc/default/grub` and then reboot to see if it has been effective.

** **CW post author's note 2**: my own experience (and the fact that it didn't work for OP earlier) strongly indicates that this file did not do anything good. If you are following this answer, I recommend you do not try to create this file in combination with the edit to `/etc/default/grub`, unless that method did not work, and the `20-intel.conf` solution did not work when tried separately.