# Fn + F3 / F4 backlight keys for keyboard brightness not working in Asus laptop?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, keyboard-backlight, asus

I'm using ASUS K501U with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Gnome-shell 3.10.4. The keyboard brightness doesn't work, since keys <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f3</kbd>/<kbd>f4</kbd> have no effect.
Is it a way to fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop

Comment: nope, this doesn't work for me,
and i asked about keybord backlight not screen,
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors tp-smapi-dkms tpb`
3. `sudo sensors-detect`

Works fine for me.

Comment: Can you please describe what are the risk of your work flow. I do your work flow in Asus Zenbook UX303UA. It just finds `coretemp` in the modules and nothing else. If you accept the changes, it will unload the modules `i2c-dev` and `cpuid`. Are you really sure that your work flow is sufficient and without complications? I extended it here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306399/16920

Comment: Can you please explain your answer little bit more. Why do you expect it to work for your target? Can expect any complications?