# Black screen after hdmi monitor unplugged

Tags: kubuntu, 16.10

I really need help. I have Kubuntu 16.10 on my laptop a everything worked. With external hdmi monitor too. But once I unplugged the monitor, then plugged it in again. And now it doesn't work without the external monitor. After login I have only black screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Fn keys didn't work, so I modified /etc/default/grub (http://askubuntu.com/a/603980/619498) and now it works :)

Muaad ElSharif: thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the keys not changing the brightness level, modify the file `/etc/default/grub` as mentioned here in Ask Ubuntu: [Brightness fn key shortcut doesn't work on ASUS laptop](https://askubuntu.com/a/603980/619498)