# Brightness keys also change the keyboard backlight

Tags: 16.04, asus, acpi

My brightness keys weren't working before, so I followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop) to make them work. The problem is that now they change screen brightness *and* the keyboard backlight. Is there any fix around this?

Comment: It really depends on the laptop. They could be connected in the hardware, in which case there would be no way to separately control them. Does something lead you to believe that they can be controlled separately? Did you previously have a different OS on the laptop, and were you able to control them separately in that OS?

Comment: On windows they are controlled separetely

Comment: And on Windows you installed (or come factory installed) some proprietary software, right? Well, that's your answer.

Comment: What is the model number of your laptop?

Comment: The laptop model is K501U