# Keyboard configuration for asus E402M

Tags: keyboard, asus

hello have install ubuntu 16.04 LTS in one asus E402M, the keyboard is UK but
I would like use accenterd letter to write in my languages "Italian", I have just try to use italian eyboard but don't work well, and when to use shift also don't work,
many function like the screen brightness, windows button, and other function does not work.
Any one have just solvedt this probelm, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Asus E402M is not (yet) listed as certified compatible: 
https://certification.ubuntu.com/models/?query=asus

For brightness: [Brightness fn key shortcut doesn't work on ASUS laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop)

There are links to other suggestions there, also.