# Brightness buttons on Hp laptop not working

Tags: 16.04, brightness, hp

**EDIT:** : The first link mentioned in the question may work for some.

In the latest hp laptops like hp-au111tx(mine), to change the brightness/backlight there are two function buttons which can be used(f2 and f3). The problem is that these two buttons are not working in Ubuntu 16.04 but working in Win10. I have a dual booted laptop. Is there a way to solve this problem.

I followed the following but there was no result:

- https://antonyagnel.com/2016/09/14/how-to-fix-brightness-control-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial-xerus/
- https://askubuntu.com/a/841903

Help required!!

Comment: For me, the [first link](https://antonyagnel.com/2016/09/14/how-to-fix-brightness-control-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial-xerus/) in your question worked (on an old HP Pavilion g4).

Comment: try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working

Answer (score 0):

First open the terminal,

```
$ xrandr --current # determine the output display, which is eDP-1 for HP x360
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.75 # --output <primary display>
```

This works for me.