# Brightness control does not work

Tags: 20.04, brightness, acpi

I have ubuntu 20.04. Brightness not workiing, it is at 100% by default. Edited the grub file in all possible ways, still not working. Installed brightness controller but still not working. My machine is an acer swift 3, running on ryzen 5 4500u with vega 6 graphics. Pls give me a soln. My eyes r hurting real bad

PS; UPDATE YOUR KERNEL GUYS. IT FINALLY WORKS FOR ME.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1281948/1158910

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brightness control of new Ryzen GPUs is properly supported by Linux kernels starting with the 5.8 version.

This version will get into Ubuntu 20.04 with a HWE stack.

Currently you can install the 5.8 kernel by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

You will run the 5.8 kernel after a reboot.

Comment: it works now with kernel 5.6.....should i again go for 5.8?? anyways thank you verrryyy m

Comment: The 5.6 kernel is not one of officially Ubuntu supported kernels except the OEM one. If brightness works for you, you can use the 5.6. But the 5.8 has better support of AMD GPUs.

Comment: yes i upgraded to 5.8. Thank you so very much. You sir, are a genius!!! I was struggling with this for 1 week.... thank god!