# how to adjust screen brightness in ununtu 20.04 LTS from terminal

Tags: command-line, brightness

I have installed xbacklight and am getting 'No outputs have backlight property' on executing

xbacklight -set 50 OR

xbacklight +10

My system directory: /sys/class/backlight is empty

I have seen some solutions for the same but am unable to change brightness from terminal.

This is the result of xrandr -q --verbose

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 975, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x975+0+0 (0x51a) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm

    Identifier: 0x21
    Timestamp:  17063948
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.1:1.1:1.1
    Brightness: 26.
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x975 (0x51a) 155.250MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2040 end 2240 total 2560 skew    0 clock  60.64KHz
        v: height  975 start  978 end  988 total 1012           clock  59.93Hz
```

please help me

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
xrandr -q
```

to learn the name of your display.
Then

```
xrandr --output <display name> --brightness <level>
```

Note: for a finer control (albeit via GUI, I am not sure it has a CLI), you can use [brighness-controller](https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

**Related**:

1. [Ubuntu 20.04 brightness adjust not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working)

Comment: Using xrandr -q, I have got the result,         Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 975, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x975+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x975      59.93*+

Comment: Using xrandr -q, I have got the result,     --- starts here --- Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 975, maximum 32767 x 32767 
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x975+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x975      59.93*+  --- ends here ---. I have used the command ---starts here --- xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 100
 --- ends here ---. I have taken XWAYLAND0 as the display name and i don't see any difference in brightness, terminal goes to new line without any terminal output

Comment: Hi sancho.s, I can't see anything like primary that on executing xrand -q

Comment: Dear sanchos, Added the reslt for xrand -q --verbose

Comment: I have installed the brightness controller but it seems changing the colour temperature of screen. I hope i could alter the screen brightness as like it happens in windows. When i dual booted ubuntu 18.04 i was able to change brightness from keyboard switches only. This could be the because i am using ubuntu in VM now

Comment: @JayB - `XWAYLAND0` is the name I was refering to. Please try with that and give feedback.

Comment: Hi sanchos! I have tried with the XWAYLAND0 as the name right then but the terminal goes to new command line with no change in backlight brightness or any other output in any way. I run it now, it's the same. After reading some answers, i think there is a lot to do with graphics driver brand and other specs of device