# How to update my just my kernel version on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: kernel

I have ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. And I want to have an LTS version as there is some software that I need that works well only on that release. But also I would like to have a newer kernel, as my laptop is quite new and simply the newer kernels are needed for it to for example have brightness buttons working correctly etc. Is there an "official" way of updating my kernel on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for the "official" method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try a mainline kernel. Search for how to install them. Or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline -y
```

To install the mainline kernel installer.

You could also upgrade to the latest oem kernel

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b -y
```

Either solution will get you a newer kernel and retain 20.04LTS

Comment: Thank you! `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b -y` worked like a charm!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found installing the brightness controller worked. First installed linux-image-5.14.0-1011-oem and the headers but before I rebooted I installed the brightness controller via:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo update
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

Dimming the brightness without dimming the RGB worked to stop the flickering.