# ubuntu reinstallation on dual boot with Win10 - several hardware pieces (wifi adapter, sound card, integrated graphics) not detected after reinstalls

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, graphics, iwlwifi

I reinstalled my Ubuntu 20.04 (on dual boot with Win 10) and my sound, wifi adapter are not discovered. Also there seems to be a problem with integrated graphics (llvmpipe shows up in Settings>About instead of what I would expect to be an Intel integrated graphics; also there is no option to manage multiple monitors). I attempted the re-installation of Ubuntu already several times, and still get these symptoms.

Strangely, during the reinstalls from bootable USB, the graphics and wifi seemed to be working just fine, but once the installation is done, they are not discovered.

I turned-off secure boot in bios, I also turned off the fast boot in Windows.

Not sure how to approach this problem "holistically" (without having to find not working devices and fixing them one by one), and why this was happening. Any ideas?

I listed all devices with `sudo lspci -v -k` but unsure what to look for there.

I also listed all devices with `sudo lshw -sanitize` and have a lot of "UNCLAIMED" there - and I guess those would be the devices I have problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tick the last checkbox when installing ? ==>

[image: Ubuntu install third-party]

Comment: yes i did, i also check just now `lshw` and have a lot of "UNCLAIMED" there (?) looks like those may be the devices that are not working properly?

Comment: Already tested with the last kernel?

Comment: I think so (`5.8.0-59-generic`)

Comment: Try with a newer one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334229/how-to-update-my-just-my-kernel-version-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: hello, updating to the latest kernel indeed helped. thanks! I am now down from 18 "unclaimed" in lshw to "just" 7. 
how to decide if those "unclaimed" that remained are OK, or if they should be addressed too? some of those "unclaimed" look like what could be ignored (smart card reader, generic usb device...) but some look pretty serious/strange, like: RAM memory, or System peripheral (Xeon E3-1200...)

Comment: Hard to say, in most case they're unclaimed because a lack of driver, think you can use ndiswrapper to use MS driver in linux. Also the support website of the constructor may help