# Brightness control is not working AMD (Ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: brightness, amd-graphics

got the problem with not working brightness control (Ubuntu 21.04). Tried updating grub but no result [from this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working).

Graphics card AMD radeon Vega 11.

Thanks beforehand

Comment: Which solution from the linked question did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem on my old Thinkpad. It is an acpi problem, which I could solve by activating the brightness control of my device (named thinkpad-acpi)

Since my hardware is different from yours just take it as a rough guide:

Created file `/etc/modconf.d/brightness.conf`

```
options thinkpad-acpi brightness_mode=1
```

So you should check your sys files for more information, about whether you have a vendor acpi which you could use. There is an excellent [article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight) that might shed some light.