# Unable to adjust brightness on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dpkg, brightness

I am on Lubuntu 20.04, and the brightness controls in the settings and in `brightness-controller` are not working.

From [Ubuntu 20.04 brightness adjust not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working), I tried using brightness controller and the following error message came up:

```
xrandr: Gamma size is 0.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/brightness-controller/init.py", line 277, in change_value_pbr
    Executor.execute_command(cmd_value)
  File "/usr/share/brightness-controller/util/executor.py", line 23, in execute_command
    subprocess.check_output(string_cmd, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'xrandr        --output default         --brightness 0.45000000000000023        --gamma 1.0000000000000007:1.0000000000000007:1.0000000000000007' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I am on a Lenovo Legion 5i with Nvidia graphics.

Comment: What do you get with a `python -V; python3 -V` ?

Comment: For both I get `Python 3.8.10`