# Ubuntu live usb is not turning on laptop backlight

Tags: dell, laptop, brightness

A friend of mine has up an old xp-era laptop and wants me to try to give it some level of usefulness. It boots up to the windows login screen just fine, so I put in my Ubuntu usb and grub came up like normal. When I selected "try/install ubuntu", it gave an error that I fixed by enabling virtualization in the bios. Next time I tried booting, it got to the screen where you select install or try, but everything was extremely dim as if the backlight was dead. But windows, the bios and grub didn't have this issue, so it can't be the hardware. I can kind of see with a flashlight and turned up the brightness slider, but nothing happened. The laptop is a dell precision m4300 with a core 2 duo and 2gb ram, so is ubuntu even usable or should I find a more lightweight os?

Comment: Is this post any use? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working

Comment: You've provided no product & release details, and if this is a LTS release of Ubuntu, which kernel stack you opted to use. Why not tell us that detail, or are you hoping we guess??  I use hardware as old as from 2007 in QA of modern releases of Ubuntu (and esp. Ubuntu *flavors*), and for some older hardware, using a version with the older kernel stack is useful; but you gave absolutely no clues as to what you tried (ie. no Ubuntu product or release details, or clue as to what ISO you used)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 brightness adjust not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working)