# Ubuntu 18.04 ASUS ZX53VW keyboard shortcuts, backlight not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04, brightness, asus

I've got a few problems with a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation on this notebook:

1. Keyboard backlight does not work.

   I've tried several `acpi_osi=` settings in GRUB (e.g. the ones listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946025/asus-rog-zephyrus-keyboard-backlight-not-working)), no success. The only change noticeable was that in some cases the touchpad was entirely disabled after boot.

   Interestingly, there is no `asus::kbd_backlight` folder in `$ ls /sys/class/leds` (althoug it has a folder named `phy0` - maybe related, not sure). So all solutions related to that folder obviously won't work.
2. Keyboard shortcuts (Fn) don't work, except for volume-related.

   Keyboard backlight and display-related (brightness etc) shortcuts don't work. Likely related to 1.
3. Brightness display slider doesn't have to a minimum value

   This is likely a bug in Gnome 3/Ubuntu 18.04, I'll probably post in Launchpad at some point: if you move the slider all the way to the leftmost position, the brightness actually drops to "zero absolute", i.e. the screen is completely blank.

The output of `/sys/class/leds/phy0-led` is:

```
brightness device max_brightness power subsystem trigger uevent
```

The output of `cat /sys/class/leds/phy0-led/brightness` is:

```
1
```

The output of `cat /sys/class/leds/phy0-led/max_brightness` is

```
1
```

The output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: If you think it's a kernel problem (and you may be right) please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a` and thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @Fabby I won't dispute the possibility, however the knowledge of what kernel is in use would certainly be useful to find out for certain.

Comment: I thought as much, @ElderGeek. I updated the question with the kernel version.

Comment: Ah.  @ElderGeek is right.  I'm shutting up and deleted all my comments.  No further clue here.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/949600/225694

Comment: I had all kinds of problems trying to run Ubuntu and other distros on this laptop. High temperature, freezing, can't control screen brightness, can't turn on keyboard backlight. Tried all the possible solutions I could find without much luck. I ended up just running Linux in VirtualBox in Windows 10 and don't have any of those problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this isn't what you want to hear, but you might want to wait awhile. HWE (hardware enablement kernels) should be available for the Ubuntu 18 series around [April of 2019.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=18.04.x+Ubuntu+Kernel+Support+Schedule.svg) It's been my experience with 16.04 and previous versions that these kernels provide better support for newer hardware (as intended).

Sadly [ASUS recommends against installing Linux on this laptop](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx3P62U8NHFTUIU/ref=ask_dp_lsw_al_hza?asin=B01LXCBXQO) and doesn't appear to be interested in driver development for Linux (at least on this platform).

For more information on the various kernels [this page in the MAAS docs](https://docs.maas.io/2.1/en/installconfig-nodes-ubuntu-kernels) gives a nice explanation.

A possible alternative to waiting would be to try a more recent [mainline kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) the most recent of which can be found [here.](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/) Be aware that this could result in unintended consequences so it's prudent to have a backup plan in case something goes awry. Considering that the issues that you are having don't make the system unusable, waiting might be the better option.

**Edit** Sometimes a [BIOS Update](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/ZX53VW/HelpDesk_BIOS/) can help, but none of the recent updates that I could find appear to address your current concerns and updating a BIOS isn't for the faint of heart and can have the unintended consequence of "bricking" your device.

**Note:** As I do not have your hardware I cannot provide a better answer than this. Hopefully someone with the ability to test (such as yourself) can provide a better answer in the future.

Comment: Great info. It seems that 16.04 has HWE support already: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack#Rolling_HWE_Stacks_for_16.04 . Perhaps I should try it out.