# Unable to change Brightness Ubuntu 13.04 Toshiba Satellite A105

Tags: brightness, toshiba-satellite

I have a Toshiba Satellite A105 s4384 running Ubuntu 13.04 and for some reason I cannot change the brightness.

Neither the function keys (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>/<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>) nor the settings work, and it is really bothersome, as I would like to occasionally decrease the brightness (long car trips where my battery doesn't last, etc.)

Does anyone have any idea? Judging by the suggested questions this seems to be a rather prevalent issue, but none seem to have an answer! I had a similar problem with 12.04 LTS before I upgraded.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script/149265#149265

Comment: @BYEAskUbuntu Hey! Your answer on there solved it! Have yet to reboot to see if it lasts, but that allows me to change the brightness (at least temporarily!) Could you post this as answer so I can mark it as such? I'll answer it for now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after quite a while [BYEAskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/33833/byeaskubuntu)'s answer solved it for me as per his answer here: [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script/149265#149265) (scroll down to his answer.)

I ran `xrandr -q | grep " connected"` and then `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness [VALUE]` and it worked!

Thanks to [BYEAskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/33833/byeaskubuntu)!

Comment: You do it. I dont mind my friend.+1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Each time I log on I have to enter "System Settings" then "Brightness and Lock" and drag the slider over to the right.  However, this setting resets upon reboot/shutdown.

If you need something more permanent, try this way, [copied from another post by Garry Cairns](https://askubuntu.com/a/156873/22949):

> Open a terminal using `Ctrl+Alt+t` and type `sudo apt-get install
>   xbacklight`. That will install
>   [`xbacklight` [image: Install xbacklight]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xbacklight)
>   if it isn't already there (I can't remember whether it's a default
>   package!).
>
> Then type `xbacklight -set x` **replacing the x with a number between
>   1 and  99** to set the percentage brightness for your screen
>   backlight. You can actually set to 0 (and I do because I hate bright
>   screens) but I understand that can cause problems on some displays so
>   I don't recommend trying it.

Comment: Neither of these work, sadly.