# screen brightness not changing after installing ubuntu 12.04. set to minimum

Tags: brightness

I installed ubuntu 12.04 32 bit on my 64 bit dell inspiron (core i3) laptop. but after installing it the screen brightness is set to minimum and the brightness up/down keys dont function.

Answer (score 0):

Check here. Solved my issue for me: [Unable to change Brightness Ubuntu 13.04 Toshiba Satellite A105](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369756/unable-to-change-brightness-ubuntu-13-04-toshiba-satellite-a105).

I ran `xrandr -q | grep " connected"` and then `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness [VALUE]` and it changed the brightness, even when I had the same issue as you. This is a relatively short-term fix, as it doesn't stick around after a reboot, but it changes the brightness if you need it, say late at night.