# Brightness Fn keys suspend the notebook

Tags: shortcut-keys, 14.10, brightness, toshiba-satellite, function-keys

In Ubuntu 14.10, everytime I press any of the "**Brightness Fn keys**" the notebook suspend, by the way the "**Sleep Fn key**" does nothing at all.

Is there a way to remap all the Fn keys manually?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me :

1) Edit /etc/default/grub and change this variable:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=legacy"

2) Edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add this line at the end of the file:

blacklist toshiba_acpi

3) Update the grub config file:

sudo update-grub

4.) Reboot.

https://askubuntu.com/a/450357

Comment: I'm using Toshiba p850 with ubuntu 14.10 and following vincentrous' answer, I blacklisted the toshiba_acpi. This caused my laptop to overheat. Still I'm in search of a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about keybinding but here is a quick fix open the terminal and type

```
xrandr -q | grep " connected"
```

then to change the screen brightness enter

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.0
```

0.0 can be anything from 0.0 to 2.0

Comment: I don't have any trouble changing the brightness, my issue is that the Fn Keys that are made for increasing and decreasing the brightness don't work, every time I press them the notebook goes to sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops will swap the fn hotkeys around meaning pressing the fn key and any f1-f12 key is really the f keys and not the alternate keys so not pressing the fn key gives you the alternate keys like adjusting the volume and brightness. If a f key is assigned to put it to sleep by the os and you hit fn and that f key it will put to sleep and pressing the fn key and the sleep key will not put it to sleep because you are really activating just that f key not the alternate sleep key. I hope i didn't make that to complicated. If not that you have something i've never heard of.

Comment: I already checked this, at my notebook BIOS menu there is an option to do so (change the f1-f12 keys to the FN, without having to press "Fn"). But changing this option did nothing, still the notebook goes to sleep mode everytime I try to increase or decrease the brightness with the shortcut keys. Thanks anyways!